# How to avoid the extension files when I compile pdf on r sweave

Tags: r, auxiliary-files, sweave

I face a problem when I compile pdf file I got many files in the working directory, for example, the files `Untitled.tex` and `Untitled.toc` along which my files `Untitled.pdf` and `Untitled.Rnw`.

Can anyone help me how to avoid these files (`Untitled.tex` and `Untitled.toc`), 
please.

Answer (score 4):

In RStudio it should be >  <kbd>Tools</kbd>  > <kbd>Global Options...</kbd> > <kbd>Sweave</kbd> > Check <kbd>Clean auxiliary output after compile</kbd> > <kbd>Apply</kbd> > <kbd>OK</kbd> but for some reason actually do not clean that files.

Funnily, that happen with  .Rnw but not .Rmd files, although both are finally converted to LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I did that and I saw it is already Check Clean auxiliary output after compile, what do you think the problem?

Comment: I guess that compilation was stopped for some reason, so withouch reach to the clean step, but doing it again without error should remove that files.

Comment: sorry I do not understand you, could you please explain more,.

Comment: I mean that the auxiliar files are created to make the PDF and should be removed after the pdf creation, but if that process is stopped for some reason (a power failure,let's say ), then the auxiliar will  be left un-removed in the hard disk, right? But really is not that. I noticed now that I have the same problem. Seem a bug of Rstudio.

Comment: See [Customizing LaTeX Options](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532257?version=1.1.463&mode=desktop). `.aux` and `.out` files are removed. `.log` files are preserved if an error is detected. Other files e.g. `synctex.gz` and `.tex` are retained.

Comment: @Ross That is the point : I expected a log  "if an error is detected", but in two computer ( of course with the clean option checked) and  a very simple file test.Rnw file compiled without errors ( `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{xx}
\section{yy}
\end{document}`),  Rstudio maintain   `test.log`,  `test.toc`,  `test.tex`, `test.synctex.gz`    and   a `test-concordance.tex`.  IMHO that is a bug.